# jQuery validate dynamic input array

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to validate a `<select>` when this is a dynamic array? Like this:

```
<select class="escolhaVidro id_material" name="id_material[]" id="id_material">
```

To clarify: This `<select>` assembled dynamically by PHP, so I do not know what are the indexes, so this way is not possible:

```
$(this).validate({
    rules: {
        "id_material[index]" : {
            required : true
        }
    }
});
```

And so strangely this plugin does not work:

```
$(this).validate({
    rules: {
        id_material : {
            required : true
        }
    }
});
```

I also tried to use a CSS `class` `required` in `<select>`, but no good.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/ -- you don't seem to be using it correctly.

Comment: What are you targeting with `$(this)`?  You have to target the `form`.

Comment: It is exactly what I have.

Comment: It's really _not exactly_ what you have if it's contained inside a `live('submit')` handler function.  This is why your code is not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Quote OP**:  "And so strangely this plugin does not work:
>  
>   `$(this).validate({ ... });`"

It's not strange.  It's not working because you have not really targeted anything.  There's no context or scope for `$(this)` to have any meaning.

You must properly target your `<form>` element:

for example, by `id`...

```
$('#myform').validate({ ... });
```

...or by [any other valid jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that targets the actual `<form></form>` you want validated.

---

Here is a generic example of how to validate a `select` element that you can easily adapt into your situation:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Gy24q/**

**Important**, the very first, or the default `option` in the `select` element **must** contain `value=""` or the `required` rule will fail.  If, for whatever reason, you cannot set this first `option`'s `value` equal to `""`, then [see this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14903827/594235) custom method workaround and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPRNd/).

**HTML**:

```html
<form id="myform">
    <select name="id_material[]">
        <option value="">please choose...</option>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
    </select>
    ....
</form>
```

Since your `name` contains brackets, `[]`, [you also must enclose your field name in quotes](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29):

**jQuery**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize plugin within DOM ready
        // other options,
        rules: {
            'id_material[]': {
                required: true
            }
        },
    });

});
```

---

The above answer assumes you know the `name` of the `select` element.  However, if you don't know the `name`, you have a couple options...

**1)**  Use `class="required"` inside the `select` element...

```
<select class="escolhaVidro id_material required" name="id_material[]" id="id_material">
```

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gy24q/4/**

**2)**  If the rules are more complex, you can add compound `rules` based on your existing `class` assignments using [the `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).

Use jQuery `.each()` if you have more than one `select` element that needs this rule...

```
// must be called after validate()
$('select.id_material').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
});
```

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gy24q/10/**

Otherwise, this will only apply the rule to *only one* `select` element with `class` `id_material`...

```
$('select.id_material').rules('add', {
    required: true
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

**Quote OP in comments:**

> Inside the function following validation is performed:
>   `$('#formOrcamento').live('submit', function() {...});` Then
>   `$(this).validate({...});` refers to: `$('#formOrcamento').validate
>   ({...});`

same as:

```
$('#formOrcamento').live('submit', function() {
    $(this).validate({ ... });
});
```

Yes, this is exactly why it's broken.

[`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) only gets called *once* on DOM ready to *initialize* the plugin.  You are not supposed to put it inside a `submit` handler.  The Validate plugin already has its own built-in event handler that captures the form's submit button.

Setup your code as per my working jsFiddle demos above.

---

**EDIT 2:**

**Quote OP in comments:**

> I'm using `jquery-ui` and this adds to the select the following:
>   `style='display: none'`. If I remove via Firebug the `display: none`,
>   then select validation occurs and displays the label error correctly.
>   What might be happening?

The Validate plugin ignores hidden elements by default. You'll need to turn that option off by adding `ignore: []` to `validate()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        ignore: [], // to allow validation of hidden elements
        // other options,
    });

});
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235) for more information.

Comment: Inside the function following validation is performed:
`$('#formOrcamento').live('submit', function() {...});`
Then `$(this).validate({...});` refers to: `$('#formOrcamento').validate ({...});`

Comment: @MayW. Take `.validate()` out of your `live.submit` handler.  It's not necessary and the most likely reason it's broken.  Follow my working demos above and see my edits.

Comment: I'm using jquery-ui and this adds to the `select` the following: `style='display: none'`. If I remove via Firebug the `display: none`, then `select` validation occurs and displays the `label` error correctly. What might be happening?

Comment: The Validate plugin ignores hidden elements by default.  You'll need to turn that option off by adding `ignore: []` to `validate()`.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/Gy24q/6/

Comment: I applied the fixes that indicated and are much better. However only one of the `select` is being validated. Then modified to, as you said after `.validate()`: `$('select.id_material').rules('add', {required: true,});` But still only one of `select` is being validated.

Comment: @MayW., yes, and that's exactly what I said was going to happen.  Go back and re-read that section of my answer... you **must** use `.each()` if you have more than one `select.id_material`.  See the demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gy24q/10/

Comment: `$('select.id_material').rules('add', {required: true,});` was not working because these `select` are added or removed as the user interacts and makes decisions, then through a `setInterval()` solved this. Another problem, which is simple but not me I saw so fast, is that the `name` from `select` were always as `name=id_material[]` then added a counter `i++` thereby: `name=id_material[i]`and everything works perfectly now.

Comment: @Sparky, Is there any link where I can check the submitting process in php or codeigniter?

Answer (score -2):

Just use emtpy brackets and make sure the name including brackets is in quotation marks (see [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference#link-fields-with-complex-names-%28brackets-dots%29)):

```
$(this).validate({
    rules: {
        "id_material[]" : {
            required : true
        }
    }
});
```