# Validating Drop Down List in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

This my attempt at validating a dropdown list. Its actually a flip switch in jquery mobile. I want to force the user to answer "yes" in order to pass validation. I'm trying to figure out a way to do this using the jquery validation plugin. This works fine for text and list boxes however, I cannot seem to get validation to work with a drop down list. I have also created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QF6h5/). Any help here is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
<body>
<form id="frmTest">
    <label for="txtName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <label for="lstAnswer">Did you enter your name?</label>
    <select id="lstAnswer" name="lstAnswer" data-role="slider">
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="butSubmit" value="Check Test" />
</form>
</body>


jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
debug: true,
success: "valid"
});
$("#frmTest").validate({
messages: {
    txtName: {
        required: "Please enter your name",
    },
    lstAnswer: {
        required: "Please select Yes",
    }        
},
rules: {
    txtName: {
        required: true
    },
    lstAnswer: {
        required: true
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896854/jquery-validate-plugin-select-list-validation

Comment: The problem seems to be when jquery mobile is introduced into this scenario

Comment: working with slider is hectic. I try always to avoid them :/ if its going to drive you crazy, replace it with a checkbox, it looks nice :)